# Location Manager Not Removing Location Updates

Tags: java, android, android-loadermanager

I am working on an application like speed meter and I am calculating current speed from my location. I just want to stop location updates if user press stop button but, it's not working for me. Please help me out.

I have tried `locationmanager.removeUpdates(AnalogSpeedMeterScreen.this);` but it is not removing updates.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code, if you expect anyone to be able to help you.  I'm not sure why you have had to qualify the parameter to removeUpdates() with AnalogSpeedMeterScreen.  It should be enough just to say 'this'.  It's possible you are passing the wrong reference to removeUpdates().

Comment: try removing locationmanager.removeCallback() method